# How to mock EntityManager in ConstraintValidator implementation

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, gradle, junit, mockito

I already have mock EntityManager in the test. 
But now I need mock EntityManager also in my real class(validator of the custom constraint annotation).

In the test I doing so

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeConstraintValidatorTest {

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

In the validator I can not do the same, because can not resolve import org.junit.runner.RunWith in Intellij Idea. 
For build I'm using Gradle.'gradle deploy' going successfully, but when I start Test I get following errors in Idea console

> Error:(6, 25) java: package org.junit.runners does not exist
>   Error:(21, 2) java: cannot find symbol   symbol: class RunWith

The reasons on which I need mock EntityManager is error below while testing

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.clients.entity.CClient
>   entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the field injection does not works, but I have found another solution of the original problem.
Before the line where I got an exception i'm wrote

```
entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@RunWith` annotation is made for test classes only. If you want to *inject* the *EntityManager* in your validation class, I would recommend using field injection.

I assume your *ConstraintValidator* has a field with the name 'entityManager'.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeConstraintValidatorTest  {
    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @InjectMocks
    private ConstraintValidator myValidator;
}
```

more information can be found [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html)

Comment: Now my test class looks like that `code`@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CorporateClientUniqueValidatorTest {

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @InjectMocks
    private ConstraintValidatorImpl validator;


    @Test
    public void create() {
  ///
    }

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}`code` The EntityManager did not  injected in validation class.

Comment: That looks to be fine. Just a tip: you only have to put the @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) or the method initMocks(). You don't need both, they basically do the same for you. Can you show me a simplified version of your Validator class? Don't drop any part with the EntityManager.

Comment: `code`@Stateless
public class CorporateClientNameUniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueName, String> {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueName constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
        /* */

        if (results.size() > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}`code`

Comment: Does your CorporateClientNameUniqueValidator have a constructor defined? If yes, you should add a standard setter and getter for your entitymanager in the CorporateClientNameUniqueValidator  class. (And in your code you should use the getEntiyManager() instead of calling entityManager directly.)

Comment: No, not have a constructor defined. I'm tried now to define  a constructor and to add setter and getter. getEntiyManager() returns null.